# Create IOrganizationServiceFactory in Console Application for Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: c#, console-application, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to create an instance of `IOrganizationServiceFactory` as I want to create multiple threads to connect to the service endpoind. To create multiple thread safe Service Contexts you can use the factory. However I can not seem to create one.

Is this possible within a C# Console Application or is it limited for only plugins and workflows ?

I can create a `OrganizationServiceProxy`, however I do not know how to proceed from here.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
var serverName = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganisationUrl"];
Uri organisationUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc", serverName));
Uri homeRealmUri = null;
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


var serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organisationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the IOrganizationServiceFactory seems to be the right approach? I would recommend just using the OrganizationService class from the Microsoft.Xrm.Client library to simplify the connection. You should be able to create several of those in separate threads and be fine.

Comment: `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` library does not support the creation of `IOrganizationService` instances on multiple threads; it only handles/caches one instance at a time. Also, configuration is tied up to the app.config. I guess it was designed with WinForms and WPF apps in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design a class implementing interface `IOrganizationServiceFactory`. This class can be made responsible for creating and issueing `IOrganizationService` instances.

I made a basic example:

```
class OrganizationServiceFactory: IOrganizationServiceFactory, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<OrganizationServiceProxy> _issuedProxies =
        new ConcurrentBag<OrganizationServiceProxy>(); 

    public IOrganizationService CreateOrganizationService(Guid? userId)
    {
        var serverName = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganisationUrl"];
        Uri organisationUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc", serverName));
        var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        var serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organisationUri, null, credentials, null);
        _issuedProxies.Add(serviceProxy);
        return serviceProxy;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var serviceProxy in _issuedProxies)
        {
            serviceProxy.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Clients of the factory can obtain `IOrganizationService` instances by calling `CreateOrganizationService(Guid? userId)`, but cannot be responsible for disposing the proxies. The factory will do that for them.

B.t.w, you can make the creation of multiple proxy-instances a bit more efficient using the `IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService>` interface, but that's another topic.

You may find this article on MSDN useful: [Optimize CRM 2011 Service Channel allocation for multi-threaded processes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/09/07/optimize-crm-2011-service-channel-allocation-for-multi-threaded-processes-using-net-task-parallel-library-tpl-and-a-thread-local-service-proxy.aspx).